# How can I set a variable in a Spring bean configuration file?

Tags: xml, spring, spring-bean

I'm initialising my spring beans in my spring XML.

```
<bean class = "com.some.class">
    <property name = "sql" value ="select :id id, 3 weight from some.table"></property>
</bean>

<bean class = "com.some.class">
    <property name = "sql" value = "select :id id, 3 weight from another.table"></property>
</bean>
```

Now I want to set that `3` in a variable in the xml somewhere. How can I do this?

Comment: See [*Using Variable Substitution from Configuration Files in Spring*](http://phillips4jc.blogspot.com/2012/04/using-variable-substitution-from.html) (and please fix your "XML" -- it's not [**well-formed**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085)).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best ways to deal with properties values in XML file in Spring, Maven and Eclipses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297157/best-ways-to-deal-with-properties-values-in-xml-file-in-spring-maven-and-eclips)