# Dynamic value to Spring Property Ref tag

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-batch, application.xml

Any way is it possible to pass dynamic value to the ref tag attribute in below code from java?

```
<bean id="jobLauncherTestUtils" class="org.springframework.batch.test.JobLauncherTestUtils" >
        <property name="job" ref="$(dynamicValue)"/>
        <property name="jobLauncher" ref="jobLauncher"/>
         <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    </bean>
```

`

Comment: Maybe you should use [Java-configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java-bean-annotation) instead of XML configuration?

Comment: @mk321 Thanks! I had also thought of that , but its an existing application. Not allowed to go for such big change. Had to do it in xml fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can load them from a file of properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297157/best-ways-to-deal-with-properties-values-in-xml-file-in-spring-maven-and-eclips#answer-13297686)

If the value should be changed at runtime you must [build and launch at runtime.](https://support.pivotal.io/hc/en-us/articles/202653068-Registering-unregistering-scheduling-and-unscheduling-Task-Scheduler-at-runtime-in-Spring-Framework-3-0-3-1-2010476-)