# How to take values from application.yml to ehcache.xml?

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, yaml

I have value of TTL in application.yml 
I want to use this TTL value from application.yml inside ehcache.xml 
How can I call that application.yml value

application.yml

```
    reset:
      servicebus:
        system-name: ${ECP_CACHE_RESET_CONSUMER_NAME:}
        notification-base-url: ${ECP_CACHE_RESET_BASEURL:}
        topic-name: ${ECP_CACHE_RESET_TOPIC:}
        cache-reset-time: 10000
```

ehcache.xml

```
<cache name="refDataCache" maxElementsInMemory="15000"
           maxEntriesLocalDisk="20000" eternal="false"
           timeToIdleSeconds="300" timeToLiveSeconds="720000" overflowToDisk="true"
           memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" />
```

I want to use this cache-reset-time value inside this ecache.xml in timeToLiveSeconds

Comment: you can find this link useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297157/best-ways-to-deal-with-properties-values-in-xml-file-in-spring-maven-and-eclips